# how do i change the ownership (to another gmail account) of a google cloud project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to change the ownership of a Google Cloud Project to another account. I could do it on a Firebase Project but I cannot see the option in Google Cloud Console to migrate the whole GC Project.

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, to migrate your project you can check this official [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing) In there you have the examples with and without an organization.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add him to the project as [Project owner](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#project-roles). You can take a look at [this to documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#grant_access) to add a team member to a project and grant them a cloud IAM role.